# how to reset variable on form clear in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a small program that on "Load" button click creates object info and populates a text field. I also have a clear button that resets everything on the form. On form load if you click the "load" button without first choosing a company from the drop down list you get an error saying "choose company first".

If you choose a company and hit "load" everything works perfectly. If you hit clear everything clears out but if you then hit "load" it fills the text field with the info from the previously chosen company instead of showing the "choose company first error".

does anyone out there have any suggestions that might help to truly clear everything when the clear button is clicked?

here is my code

```
  Public Sub btn_LoadScript_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_LoadScript.Click
        'get vb script
        If cb_COID.SelectedItem = String.Empty Then
            lbl_FormMainUserMessage.Text = "Select a Company Code"
        Else

            Try
                Dim co As Object = M3System.GetEntity("MillCompany.Company", cb_COID.SelectedItem)
                Dim script As Object = co.Scripting.ItemByKey("PaycheckCalc")
                'Dim script = co.Scripting.ItemByKey("CCalcCode")

                Scintillatb_Script.Text = script.vbscript

            Catch ex As Exception
                lbl_FormMainUserMessage.Text = ex.Message
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
 Private Sub btn_Reset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Reset.Click
        'clear form
        For Each cb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
            cb.Text = String.Empty
            cb.SelectedItem = String.Empty
        Next cb
        For Each tb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            tb.Text = String.Empty
        Next tb
        For Each lb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
            lb.Text = String.Empty
        Next lb
        Scintillatb_Script.Text = ""

    End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't think anyone will have any useful suggestions.....

Comment: how do you expect people to help without code?

Comment: I suggest you debug the app...use BreakPoints and callstack to see what is botched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your dropdown selected index -1.
Add to your clear code :

```
 YourDropdown.selectedindex = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you clearing the drop down list? it seems that the text of the drop down list is cleared, but not the selected index or selected item of that drop down list.

That's why when clicking load for the second time after clearing the UI, it still loads the information, instead of mentioning the error message "Choose company first error"